# SQL Server 2016 Management studio regular update

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

Since ssms is now separated from the SQL Server installation, what is the easiest way to to keep it up to date withought downloading the entire setup again? I couldn't find a check for update button anywhere.

Comment: No matter what, you'll need to download the whole SSMS setup package, which can be up to 800 MB.

Comment: @PeterSchott I'm afraid you're right, and it's pretty sad. Regular updates are a good thing but having to download close to 1GB worth of installer doesn't help.

Comment: Well, it's _better_ in SSMS 17.x, but the incremental update packages are still a bit large. Still, better than downloading the whole thing if you already have it installed.

Answer (score 8):

**Update 03/01/2018:**
You don't need to install the whole package.. you can click on below highlighted link which is around 300MB in size ..

As you can see in below screenshot, you are provided with an option to install latest version(17.5) or just upgrade from 17.X version to latest version..

[image]

**Old :**

You can't download SSMS with out installing whole setup

1.If you are on windows10 latest version.,you will receive a popup which shows  an update available whenever you login to SSMS

[image]

2.you also can check by going to tools-->updates in SSMS and you get below screen  and clicking on update will lead you to installer page

[image]

3.You also can download installer from this page(which will always install latest version)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx

**References:**
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/07/an-update-to-sql-server-management-studio-is-available/

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question, which states explicitly **"without downloading the entire setup again"**. The only valid answer may well be that it is not possible, but at least you should make that clear. Your answer makes it appear as if it *is* possible, but really it's just 3 ways to get what the OP *doesn't* want.

Comment: @MarioDS you are correct,l missed it ,I will update the answer once I am back at a computer

Comment: good catch on the bottom link being a smaller package. I guess it's something at least.